# How to add auto slider into a owl-carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-demo1").owlCarousel({
                    items : 5,
                    itemsDesktop : [1000,5], 
                    itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], 
                    itemsTablet: [600,2], 
                    itemsMobile : false 
    });
});
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: i want to add an auto slider in this jquery. how could i add in this???

Comment: Unless readers can see how it is failing, I am not sure the question can stay open. Are you able to support your question with a JS Fiddle and a more complete description of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to Owl Carousel's documentation:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

You can added a property `loop` to the object you're passing to the `owlCarousel` method.

Just set it as true:

`loop: true`

Comment: Oh no sorry dear.. i want an automatic time loop carousel in this code.